# Converting CSV-backed dataframe to hive table loses multiline support

Tags: sql, scala, csv, apache-spark, hive

I have a CSV file full of names and long-form message data. The message data is in a multiline format with newlines embedded in the data. The fields have been quoted, and I've parsed it successfully into a Spark dataframe like so:

```
scala> val df =spark.read.option("parserLib", "univocity")
.option("multiLine", true)
.option("header", true)
.option("inferSchema", true)
.option("quoteAll", true)
.csv("/data.csv");
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Name: string, Message: string ... 17 more fields]
```

This produces the expected data in the `Name` column:

```
scala> df.limit(10).select("Name").show
+-------+
|   Name|
+-------+
| foobar|
| foobar|
| foobar|
| foobar|
| foobar|
| foobar|
| foobar|
| foobar|
| foobar|
| foobar|
+-------+
```

The problem happens when I try to convert this to a hive table:

```
scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("events")
scala> sqlContext.sql("create table s_events as select * from events");
res52: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []
```

Displaying the data now shows that the CSV parser is no longer escaping the embedded newlines, and is instead parsing them as a row separator:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select Name from s_events limit 10").show();
+--------------------+
|                Name|
+--------------------+
|              foobar|
|              foobar|
|              foobar|
|              foobar|
|              foobar|
|Sent: Tuesday, 30...|
|To: 'personxyz   ...|
|Subject: RE: ABSD...|
|                    |
|     Hello Person,  |
+--------------------+
```

Previously,I've tried loading directly within Hive, but Hive had the same result. Some googling told me that the workaround for Hive not supporting multiline records in CSV was to side-load through Spark as above, but this appears not to work either.

Is there a way to convince Hive that newlines in quoted regions are now row separators, or will I need to clean the data before trying to load it?

Comment: This is usually due to formatting issue in the source file. Can you share a sample data set, or snapshot of the source file?